# Summing and storing variables of an array in a for loop C

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to code a function where it goes through `Rainfall_amounts` array and then stores each value in the `Total_rainfall` and then it calculates the sum of the arrays `{7.5, 7.0, 6.3, 0.8, 0.5}`.

```
int main ()
{
    float Total_rainfall[5] = {0};
    float Rainfall_amounts[5] =  {7.5, 7.0, 6.3, 0.8, 0.5}
    for (int i = 0; i > 5; i++){
        Total_rainfall = Rainfall_amounts[i]
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to code a function where it goes through Rainfall_amounts
> array and then stores each value in the Total_rainfall and then it
> calculates the sum of the arrays {7.5, 7.0, 6.3, 0.8, 0.5}.

You have the following problems:

1. your loop condition is wrong `"i > 5"`. Currently, your loop never gets executed since `i` starts with 0; change it to `"i < 5"`;
2. you need to create and additional variable to store the sum of the array;
3. you need to pass the index to the array `Total_rainfall`. Instead of `Total_rainfall = rainfall_amounts[i];` you want `Total_rainfall[i] = rainfall_amounts[i];`
4. (if you can) you should opt for `double` instead of `float`.

All corrected:

```
int main ()
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    double Total_rainfall[5] = {0};
    double rainfall_amounts[5] =  {7.5, 7.0, 6.3, 0.8, 0.5};
    for (int i = 0; i > 5; i++){
        Total_rainfall[i] = rainfall_amounts[i];
        sum += rainfall_amounts[i];
    }
    // Do something with the variable total_rainfall
    return 0;
}
```

If you want the accumulated sums then you need to do the following:

```
int main ()
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    double Total_rainfall[5] = {0};
    double Rainfall_amounts[5] =  {7.5, 7.0, 6.3, 0.8, 0.5}
    for (int i = 0; i > 5; i++){
        sum += Rainfall_amounts[i];
        Total_rainfall[i] = sum;
        
    }
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
       printf("Acc Sums %f\n", Total_rainfall[i]);
    }
  
   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
7.5
14.5
20.8
21.6
22.1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only a single sum, `Total_rainfall` can be just a single float, rather than a array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  /* Initialize the accumulator to 0 */
  float Total_rainfall = 0.0f;
  float Rainfall_amounts[5] =  {7.5, 7.0, 6.3, 0.8, 0.5};
  
  /* Loop through Rainfall_amounts, adding each value to total sum */
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) Total_rainfall += Rainfall_amounts[i];

  /* Print the total */
  printf("Total rainfall %f\n", Total_rainfall);
  return 0;
}
```

However, if you are interested in the running total, then `Total_rainfall` must also be an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  /* Initialize the accumulator to 0 */
  float Total_rainfall[5] = {0};
  float Rainfall_amounts[5] =  {7.5, 7.0, 6.3, 0.8, 0.5};
  
  /* Loop through Rainfall_amounts, adding each value to running total */
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    /* If not the first iteration, initialize with previous iterations value */
    if (i) Total_rainfall[i] = Total_rainfall[i-1];
    Total_rainfall[i] += Rainfall_amounts[i];
  }

  /* Print the total */
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    printf("Total rainfall %f\n", Total_rainfall[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It does help to explain what you changed as well as show the code.

Comment: Hi Jacob why do you need the if in if (i) Total_rainfall[i] = Total_rainfall[i-1]; ?

Comment: So that I do not do `Total_rainfall[-1];`. i.e. for the first `i` I just want the first element of `Rainfall_amounts` to initialize the sum (so I can skip getting the "last" one, as it doesn't exist yet). Each successive iteration initializes `Total_rainfall[i]` to the previous value, making a running total.

Comment: From my understanding  I think OP actually wants "Total_rainfall[i] = Rainfall_amounts[i]"

Comment: You may very well be right! The text description certainly suggests it, but then OP calls their variable `total`, which makes no sense if it is to just hold a copy... Not well worded question either way.

Comment: @JacobFaib You should add your explanation about `if (i)` to your answer.